# how to get approximate searching results in sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server

How to write sql procedure to get matching results while searching for string values.It should search by the similarity of the characters entered by user. For instance Ahmmed, Ahmad, Ahmmad or Mohammad, Mohammed, Mohamad etc should display all similar names while executing search.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Full-text search?

Comment: I am a newbie to sqlserver so is it possible to get similar values while doing full text search

Comment: You can look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess you need AI for that but, you can use the `like` keyword to do wildcards.

e.g.

`$search_string = 'Ahm'; //or Moha
$query = SELECT column FROM tableName WHERE column LIKE '$search_string%'; //starts with the $search_string`

**or**

`$query = SELECT column FROM tableName WHERE column LIKE '%$search_string'; //ends with the $search_string`

**or**

`$query = SELECT column FROM tableName WHERE column LIKE '%$search_string%'; //starts and/or ends with the $search_string`

**take note of the %**

Comment: Thanks but i need to get mohd,muhammed,ahmed etc when i search for mohamed.How is that possible?

Comment: what do you mean? what specific string would you use to search **mohd,muhammed,ahmed?**

Comment: when i search for mohamed i should get all matching string values like mohd,muhammed,ahmed

Comment: oh, I guess you need to split the string into syllables and use it all in the query...

Comment: can u pls provide any sample code to accomplish this

Comment: At first, LIKE search with wild card may go slowly. Second, you cannot use word-forms. The OP need s full-text for that kind of stuff.